# In SQL Server 2000 how do you add 0's to beginning of number to fill nchar(n)

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm trying to add 0's to the beginning of an `nchar(n)`. Is their a format function in SQL Server 2000 to add 0's to an int so that it will always have n number of digits with leading 0's:

example

```
int         nchar(n)
1           0000..1
2           0000002
3           0000003
...
10          0000010
11          0000011
...
100         0000100
...
1000        0001000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. for `n=12`

```
DECLARE @foo bigint
DECLARE @bar bigint

SET @foo=12345678901
SET @bar=12

SELECT RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(@foo AS VARCHAR(12)),12) 
SELECT RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(@bar AS VARCHAR(12)),12)
```

Beware! This won't work for numbers with more than n digits!

Comment: Is it possible to make to an n value of Digits with leading 0's?  There are like 15 different lengths in this system.  Thx.

Comment: Ahh I didn't see you n=12  I can just put that in a function or whatever and replace teh 12 with the n?  Cool thx.

Comment: @Cyber That is possible, but you also have to adjust the `'00...0'` or make it big enough

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for being slightly off-topic, but are you really sure that this is a problem that should be dealt with on a database level rather than in presentation level? I mean, database can and should store those numbers as-is, and only in presentation code do you add all the leading zeroes.

Comment: Its more for a where clause.  I need to verify a certain numbers match an rfid tag, and when another system I have no control over pulls these numbers it has leading 0's I need to be able to compare these fields to an ident field to ensure that they match the text rfid tag given.