# How can we use prefix as zero in SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can we use zero's in prefix of the number column feedback_refno like

select @refno = '0001'

i need to insert this value into that column feedback_refno but it is inserting like 1 only..but i need those prefix before those 1

I have tried like this

```
declare @refno int
select  max(feedback_refno)+1 from EDK_Customer_Feedback(nolock)

if not exists(select feedback_refno from EDK_Customer_Feedback(nolock))
Begin 
    select @refno = '0001'
end     
else
Begin
    select @refno
End
insert into EDK_Customer_Feedback values(@refno)
```

I need the result like 0002 then 0003 like that but it is giving like 2 then 3..

Any suggestion?

Comment: Since you declared refno as an int it will always turn 0001 into 1. Why is it so important that the refno is 000[0-9]* ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(varchar,feedback_refno),4) AS NUM FROM EDK_Customer_Feedback;
```

Answer (score 1):

`@refno`is of type `int`, so leading zeros wont work. If you change it to `varchar(4)` you can use these two answers:

[In SQL Server 2000 how do you add 0's to beginning of number to fill nchar(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672951/in-sql-server-2000-how-do-you-add-0s-to-beginning-of-number-to-fill-ncharn/5673051#5673051)

[In SQL Server 2000 how do you add {n} number of 0's to a nchar(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673183/in-sql-server-2000-how-do-you-add-n-number-of-0s-to-a-ncharn/5673208#5673208)